# Finding a path travel cost closest to a given value

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, multidimensional-array, path-finding

I have been stuck on a problem recently. I have to find the cost of a path from the top left corner to the bottom right corner of a multidimensional array of integers. This path's cost has to be the greatest cost that does not go over a certain provided value.

The cost of a path is defined as the sum of the values of the array indexes that this path travels through. The start of each path is always the top left corner, and the end of each path is always the bottom right corner. Also, you can only travel to the right or toward the bottom.

Let's say this is the multidimensional array that I am to use for this problem, and the provided value is 12.

```
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 2 | 5 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

This is the correct path that I am supposed to find. The cost for this path is 11, it is the highest cost of any path that is below or equal to the given value.

```
+---+---+---+
| X | X | X |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | X |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 1 | X |
+---+---+---+
```

I have attempted to solve this problem in Python, but I cannot see where I am going wrong. Here is a segment of my code below.

```
def answer (food, grid):

    # Grid is N*N in size
    n = len(grid)

    # Memoize a given function
    def memoize (f):
        memo = {}
        def helper (r, c, k):
            i = c + (r * n)
            if i not in memo:
                memo[i] = f(r, c, k)
            return memo[i]
        return helper

    # Get cost function
    def get_cost (r, c, k):

        if r >= n or c >= n:
            return -1
        if k < grid[r][c]:
            return -1
        if r == n - 1 and c == n - 1:
            return grid[r][c]

        down = get_cost(r + 1, c, k - grid[r][c])
        right = get_cost(r, c + 1, k - grid[r][c])

        if down < 0 and right < 0:
            return -1

        return grid[r][c] + max(down, right)

    # Memoize the get cost function
    get_cost = memoize(get_cost)

    return get_cost(0, 0, food)

print answer (12, [[0, 2, 5], [1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1]])
```

I am always getting the answer of 16, where I should be getting the answer of 11. Can anyone help me with this?

Edit:

I changed my memoize code to include the given food value in the index. And I have gotten the correct answer. However, there are still other cases where it does not work. (I am not provided the input in these cases so I cannot see where it went wrong).

Here is my updated code.

```
# Memoize a given function
    def memoize (f):
        memo = {}
        def helper (r, c, k):
            i = (k * food) + (c + (r * n))
            if i not in memo:
                memo[i] = f(r, c, k)
            return memo[i]
        return helper
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the food argument is?

Comment: The food argument is the given value I am to base finding the cost of the path around. The cost of the path I find has to have the greatest cost of all possible paths while not going over the food value. Sorry for the misnomer on that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your memoize function to something like this:

```
def memoize (f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(*args):
        if args not in memo:
            memo[args] = f(*args)
        return memo[args]
    return helper
```

---

```
grid = [[0,2,5],[1,1,3],[2,1,1]]
answer(12, grid)
# 11
```

---

As long as your arguments are hashable, you can use `*args` as a argument to your function and `args` as the key to the memoization cache. This is the same as using a tuple of the arguments as the key.

```
def fn(*args):
    print(args)

fn(1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

The original memoization cache keys made up by `i = c + (r * n)` excluded taking into account the `k` and also allowed for possible collisions for different c and r combinations.

Comment: This works! I will accept this answer, but I wanted you to see this comment first. Would you mind explaining how this fixes my problem?

Comment: The key you are trying to use is `i = c + (r * n)` might be for several sets of arguments. for example, `c = 3, r = 1, n = 3` and `c = 0, r = 2, n = 3` would be the same key of `6`, but shouldn't return the same value from cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share a different approach using backtracking:

```
def find_path(food, grid):

    n = len(grid)

    def worker(cost, path):
        row, col = path[-1]
        if row == n - 1 and col == n - 1:
            # we reached the bottom right corner, exit now
            return cost, path

        possible_paths = []
        if row < n - 1:
            # we can go down
            cost_down = cost + grid[row+1][col]
            path_down = list(path)
            path_down.append((row+1, col))
            possible_paths.append(worker(cost_down, path_down))
        if col < n - 1:
            # we can go to the right
            cost_right = cost + grid[row][col+1]
            path_right = list(path)
            path_right.append((row, col+1))
            possible_paths.append(worker(cost_right, path_right))

        # a path is valid, if its cost is
        # less or equal to the food available
        valid_paths = [item for item in possible_paths
                       if item is not None
                       and item[0] <= food]

        if valid_paths:
            return max(valid_paths, key=lambda x: x[0])

        return None

    return worker(grid[0][0], [(0, 0)])
```

The algorithm recursively traverses through the array and keeps looking for all possible paths. If a paths cost is above the limit (`food`), it is being discarded; otherwise every possible next step is being tried. When reaching the bottom right corner, the worker function terminates and the different paths are being compared.

This way also arrays without any possible path to go can be detected:

```
print(find_path(12, [[0, 2, 5],
                     [1, 1, 3],
                     [2, 1, 1]]))
# (11, [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)])

print(find_path(12, [[0, 2, 5],
                     [1, 1, 3],
                     [2, 1, 10]]))
# None

print(find_path(42, [[3, 8, 6, 5],
                     [1, 5, 3, 9],
                     [1, 5, 8, 1],
                     [2, 1, 9, 4]]))
# (42, [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3)])
```